# RecyclerView with enlarged first visible item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to find solution for RecyclerView with enlarged first visible item like [here](https://dribbble.com/shots/2951375-Swipe-cards-interaction-professional-project).

I started with adding ScrollListener to RecyclerView and catching IDLE_STATE, but of course item is enlarging when we stop scrolling, but I want to changing size of item like example above. How can I start with that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like they have a scroll listener that as it offsets in the X direction it grows by an equal number of pixels in the Y position. Then Set a minHeight and maxHeight on your image view so it never shrinks or grows passed the sizes you are looking for.